# How to employ a MagicMock spec_set or spec on a method?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest.mock

I am trying to use a method as a `spec_set` on a `MagicMock`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25323517/11163122 provides a nice example of an unexpected call signature resulting in an `Exception`.  Unfortunately, I can't get it to work out for a method.

How can I get the below code snippet to error out, given the calls don't match the spec?

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class Foo:
    def bar(self) -> None:
        """Some method I want to use as a spec."""

mocking_foo_bar_1 = MagicMock(name="with spec", spec=Foo.bar)
mocking_foo_bar_2 = MagicMock(name="with spec_set", spec_set=Foo.bar)

# These aren't raising, even though they don't match the spec
mocking_foo_bar_1("this", "should", "raise")
mocking_foo_bar_2("this", "also", "should", "raise")
```

I am using Python 3.8+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`spec` and `spec_set` are used for limiting the set of attributes a `Mock` is allowed to access. For functions, there's [`create_autospec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.create_autospec).

> Functions or methods being mocked will have their arguments checked to ensure that they are called with the correct signature.

Since `bar` is an instance method of `Foo`, you will also need to create an instance of `Foo` to get the expected function signature.

```py
from unittest.mock import create_autospec

mocking_foo_bar = create_autospec(Foo().bar)

mocking_foo_bar("this", "should", "raise")
```

This raises an error:

```
TypeError: too many positional arguments
```