# Test a function called in else condition

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, pytest

I have written a code where I am calling a function in the else case which returns a string. I have mocked it and asserted it to be called once. But this is failing for some reason. This decreases my code coverage with 1 line just for `get_sync_column()` in the else condition below.

**Original Function**

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class RMTable():
    sync_column: ClassVar[str] = None

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        if self.sync_column is None:
            object.__setattr__(self, "sync_column", self.cal_sync_column())

    def cal_sync_column(self) -> str:
        if not feature_flag():
            return "_synced"
        else:
            return get_sync_column() #returns str
```

**Test Function**

```
def test_sync_column():
     with patch("my_module.feature_flag") as feature_flag_mock:
         with patch("my_module.get_sync_column") as mock_sync_column:
             feature_flag_mock.return_value = True
             rm_table_mock = MagicMock(spec=RMTable)
             rm_table_mock.cal_sync_column.return_value = "FLAG_1"
             result = rm_table_mock.cal_sync_column()
             assert result == "FLAG_1"
             mock_sync_column.assert_called_once()
```

**ERROR**

```
AssertionError: Expected 'get_sync_column' to have been called once. Called 0 times.
```

Comment: it looks like there's a typo in your code. In the test function, you have `crm_table_mock` instead of `rm_table_mock`.

Comment: sorry, please ignore the typo's

Comment: is `get_sync_column()` part of the class? because then it should be `self.get_sync_column()` in `cal_sync_column`

Comment: `get_sync_column()` is not part of the class it's outside the class. I'm facing an issue with how to test this 
```else: return get_sync_column()```

Comment: The problem is simply that `rm_table_mock` isn't actually an instance of `RMTable`, but rather a `Mock` object that doesn't have methods with logics of those of the actual `RMTable`. If your goal is to test `RMTable.cal_sync_column`, you should create a fixture of an actual `RMTable` object so that `mock_sync_column` would be called when the `cal_sync_column` method is called.

Answer (score 0):

#### Create an instance of `RMTable`

You have to create an instance of `RMTable` and not an instance of `MagicMock` so the most important change is in the following substitution:

```
rm_table_mock = MagicMock(spec=RMTable) ---> rm_table = RMTable()
```

It is not enough to set `spec=RMTable`, because it only forces the instance `rm_table_mock` to have attributes declared inside `RMTable` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323361/what-is-spec-and-spec-set/25323517#25323517) to get some info about `spec`).
So when you execute the instruction `rm_table_mock.cal_sync_column()` it doesn't execute the real method `cal_sync_column()` but only call a mock object which doesn't call the function `get_sync_column()`.

#### The test code with changes

If you use the following test code the test is passed:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock, Mock
from my_module import RMTable

def test_sync_column():
    with patch("my_module.feature_flag") as feature_flag_mock:
        with patch("my_module.get_sync_column") as mock_sync_column:
            feature_flag_mock.return_value = True
            #rm_table_mock = MagicMock(spec=RMTable)   # <--- your instruction is commented
            # creation of a real instance of the class RMTable 
            rm_table = RMTable()
            #rm_table_mock.cal_sync_column.return_value = "FLAG_1"   # <--- your instruction is commented
            # set return value for the mock of the function get_sync_column() 
            mock_sync_column.return_value = "FLAG_1"
            #result = rm_table_mock.cal_sync_column()   # <--- your instruction is commented
            result = rm_table.cal_sync_column()
            assert result == "FLAG_1"
            mock_sync_column.assert_called_once()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_sync_column()
```